# How to use regexp to not match HTML tags that have certain tags inside them?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xpath

I have a link like this that I want to match with regexp:

```
<a href="tel:something">something</a>
```

I managed to match it with `<a[^>]+tel:.*?>.*?<\/a>`

But I don't want to match links that have `<span></span>` nested inside them:

```
<a href="tel:[some_numbers]"><span class="hello">Hello</span>[some_numbers]</a>
```

I tried to use negative lookahead `(?!(<\/?span[^>]*>))` to exclude `<span></span>`  but it didn't work. My regex below:

```
/<a[^>]+tel:.*?>(?!(<\/?span[^>]*>)).*?<\/a>/ig
```

Comment: Javascript has native XPath support. What is the source of your HTML string? There is literally zero reason for regex unless you'll be processing the output of `text()` in some way.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into XPath! Source of HTML string: 
var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;

Comment: Never parse html with regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @DrMe I see, see my answer. You can skip straight to the `var iterator` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this with XPath:

```
// Our HTML source
var s = `<a href="tel:something">something1</a>
<a href="tel:[some_numbers]"><span class="hello">Hello1</span>[some_numbers]</a>
<a href="tel:something">something2</a>
<a href="tel:[some_numbers]"><span class="hello">Hello2</span>[some_numbers]</a>
<a href="tel:something">something3</a>
<a href="tel:[some_numbers]"><span class="hello">Hello3</span>[some_numbers]</a>`;

// Create a root div because XML requires a single root element
var div = document.createElement('div');

// Set the innerHTML to our string
div.innerHTML = s;

// Find <a> tags with no direct child <span> tag(s)
var iterator = document.evaluate('//a[not(span)]', div, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

// Set the iterator
var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();

// Loop the iterator and log the node found
while (thisNode) {
  
  console.log(thisNode);
  
  thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kad3ouqL/

This should yield:

```
<a href="tel:something">something1</a>
<a href="tel:something">something2</a>
<a href="tel:something">something3</a>
```

Comment: @DrMe Great! If it helped you solve your issue then please feel free to mark my answer as accepted :)