# Select all whole divs with specific class using Regex for VSC

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have a tonne of code like this in a massive file and I simply want to delete all divs with the `qt` class.

```
    <div class="qt">
      <div class="qy"> Standard Delivery</div>
      <div class="qu">€1.95/$2.99</div>
    </div>
    <div class="qe" data-country="kw.svg">
      <p class="qr"> Kuwait </p>
    </div>
    <div class="qt">
      <div class="qy"> Standard Delivery</div>
      <div class="qu">€1.95/$2.99</div>
      <div class="qs"> Express Delivery</div>
      <div class="qb">€2.95/$3.99</div>
    </div>
    <div class="qe" data-country="ml.svg">
      <p class="qr"> Malawi </p>
    </div>
```

I would like to select all divs with the `qt` class up to the matching closing div in VSC (find and replace). How would we go about doing that especially given there are a varying number of other `</div>` tags inside the div we want to select?

Comment: This may be too complicated for regex.  I know how I would program this.  If you can tell me what programming/scripting languages you're comfortable with, I can write a quick script to do it for you.

Comment: that would be amazing.. i'm using js

Comment: You should 100% use XPath for this. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/65290030/2191572 for a JS starting point.

Comment: ***IF*** (a big if) all your code is as well-formatted as what you showed, then `(^\s*<div class="qt">)[\s\S]*?(^\s*<\/div>\n)` works since the ending `</div>` for each `qt` class is on its own row.  See https://regex101.com/r/LxCr6k/1.  I.e., all the inner divs are one-liners.   Otherwise this won't work.

Comment: This seems a little more robust: `(^\s*<div class="qt">\n)(^\s*<div class="q[^t]"[\s\S]*?<\/div>\n)+(^\s*<\/div>\n)`, see https://regex101.com/r/LxCr6k/2.  You can have those inner divs as non-one-liners.  But it also assumes there are no inner `qt` divs to an outer `qt` div.

Comment: omg i didnt think it was possible, can u copy this into the answer so i can accept it.. genius.. if u have time could u run through the diff tags ??

Comment: Which answer are you interested in or both?  And we can assume that all your code is similarly formatted, inner divs are one-liners, as you showed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, if your code is similarly formatted to that portion you showed, it becomes easier to do this with find/replace.  For instance:

`(^\s*<div class="qt">)[\s\S]*?(^\s*<\/div>\n)`  find and replace with nothing.

This form requires that your inner div's are one-liners like

`<div class="qy"> Standard Delivery</div>` where the entire element is on one-line.

See https://regex101.com/r/LxCr6k/1

If those inner div's are not necessarily one-liners, this is the simplest version I found that fits your data:

`^\s*<div class="qt">[\s\S]*?<\/div>\n^\s*<\/div>\n`

see https://regex101.com/r/LxCr6k/6

To explain this latter one:

`^\s*<div class="qt">`  find a `qt` class div

`[\s\S]*?<\/div>\n^\s*<\/div>\n` go, newlines or characters, until 2 consecutive `<\/div>`'s.

Now this version does require that of the 2 consecutive ending `</div>` tags following a `qt` class opener that the second represents the closing tag of the `qt` opening tag.  So if your data could look like this:

```html
<div class="qt">
   <div class="qy"> Standard Delivery</div>
   <div class="qu">€1.95/$2.99
     <div class="qu">€1.95/$2.99</div>  <= inner tag here
   </div>
</div>
```

than these regexes won't work.  Nested tags are notoriously "hard" to handle with a single regex.  Only you know if your data allows this last regex to work.  Your data as presented looks regular and simple enough to allow a regex approach to work.

Comment: this is perfect, thanks

Comment: I used this to get what I also needed, xms class with any number of closing p tags and an ending /div tag.. worked like a charm and with varying amounts of p tags.. thanks for your help!: ^\s*<div class="xms">[\s\S]*?<\/p>\n^\s*<\/div>\n