# How do you use Xpath to find All anchor tags "In General" within a div Inner html

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

This question feeds off of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65289753/how-to-use-regexp-to-not-match-html-tags-that-have-certain-tags-inside-them/65290030#65290030).

I just want to find any anchor tags in a string. The following example resembles the issue above. except I just want to detect anchor tags using xpath. And angular preferably. Using ViewChild. Any solution with javascript is accepted.

```
// Our HTML source
var s = `Some Html String <a href="#">something1</a>`;

// Create a root div because XML requires a single root element
var div = document.createElement('div');

// Set the innerHTML to our string
div.innerHTML = s;

// Find any <a> tags
var iterator = document.evaluate('//a]', div, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);

// Set the iterator
var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();

// Loop the iterator and log the node found
while (thisNode) {
  console.log(thisNode);
  thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: There is an error with the XPath expression to begin with - `//a]` should, most likely, be simply `//a`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer.

```
const desc = this.description.value;
const div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = desc;
const iterator = document.evaluate('//a', div, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
const anchors = iterator.iterateNext();
while (anchors) {
  this.toastr.error("To better improve service, external links are not permitted.");
  return false;
}
```